# Angular with D3 js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

i have created  scale dynamically by using eval function  in D3 but when i used d3 with angular the eval function was not working properly and through error while i called the scale .

```
TypeError: e.copy is not a function
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/app/d3.v3.min.js:5:13917)
    at http://localhost:3000/app/d3.v3.min.js:3:15103
    at Y (http://localhost:3000/app/d3.v3.min.js:1:4505)
    at Array.Co.each (http://localhost:3000/app/d3.v3.min.js:3:15078)
    at Array.n (http://localhost:3000/app/d3.v3.min.js:5:13838)
    at Array.Co.call (http://localhost:3000/app/d3.v3.min.js:3:15178)
    at Scope.HistoricalGraph.$scope.draw (http://localhost:3000/app/beanstalk/yhgraph/historicalgraph/historicalgraph.controller.js:418:26)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> `enter code here`(http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14432:15), <anonymous>:2:203)
    at expensiveCheckFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15485:18)
    at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:25018:17)
```

Comment: `eval` is evil try to avoid it. put some code in you question

Comment: but how to create variable dynamically in angular js..
i mean to say that suppose i have 3 channel like 
var channel = ["x","y","z"];
so i want to declare 3 variable dynamically and assign some value . how can i do 
var x = some vale 
var y = some value 
if i use eval function in normal js then it will be fine but in angular it will give some error

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic object like:

```
var channelsObject = {};
for(var i = 0;i <channel.length; i++){
  channelsObject[channel[i]] = {};
}
```

This way you will get object like this:

```
{
   x:{},
   y:{},
   z:{}
}
```

One should always avoid using eval.